# Blender Character looks abnormally smooth

Tags: light

I'm assuming its the lighting but if not will that mean I'll have to retexture my entire character?

[image]

Comment: Define 'Abnormally smooth'. How is your render different from what you were expecting?

Comment: If you notice, the character's hood has a different shading from the rest of her body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hood may have had smooth shading applied to it.  To remove this, I have two solutions:

1. If the character is one object, then select it. On the tools tab of the Tool Shelf there is an option under Shading called flat. Select that and the whole mesh should have flat shading.
2. If the character is multiple objects, then select the hood. Then repeat the step above to apply flat shading.

   [image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: That helped alot thanks man! ||One more issue to solve unfortunately, the character is transparent for some reason,is there a setting of some sort I can edit this?||

Comment: Transparent in the render?

Comment: yep ____________________

Comment: If you look real closely at the image you'll see her hair pops out from the rest of the image

Comment: Is it a separate mesh?

Comment: Joined, but I didnt find out that the sun was emitting too much bright lighting on the character as well,is there a way to change it's intensity?

Comment: Can you link a .blend file?

Comment: @Joe if you need help with something else than the original question please ask it as a different question. That way it's easier for everybody else to search and find information.